# How to create and save a large dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, dataset, save, out-of-memory

I have a tensor dimension 200 x 200 x 200 x 3. I wanna generate a dataset of 7000 of these tensors in MATLAB to be saved in a single .mat file (or other extensions that can be read in Python) of size 7000 x 200 x 200 x 200 x 3. How to do so in a loop without storing these variables in memory but saving them directly in the file?

Comment: How do you want to load the tensors later? Do you need to load more than one at the same time? Why not just use files with names `'tensor0001'.mat`, `'tensor0002.mat'` etc, one for each tensor?

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to use it as a training dataset. Each tensor should be the input of a CNN. I never came across datasets where each entry is a single file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a name based on your variable and simply store that in the same .mat file.
You'll need to add the '-append' flag so the file doesn't get overwritten.
You'll probably have to remove the temporary variables at the end of the loop too.

Something like:

```
for i = 1:10
  tensor = newTensor();
  eval(['tensor_' num2str(i)] '=tensor;');
  save(['path/tensor_.mat'], ['tensor_' num2str(i)], '-append');
  eval(['clearvars tensor_' num2str(i) ';']);
end
```

Someone asked something very similar on their website
https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/236354-saving-mat-files-in-a-for-loop

Comment: is separating each tensor feasible for reading them in Python and using them for training of a deep learning architecture?

Comment: It depends what type/shape is your input. If the input layer takes inputs of size 200x200x200x3, you can train it with minibatches of your tensors. If you mean, you wanna break it even further (as in splitting each channel), you might need to recompose them when you read from Python. As in, you read the three channels independently, reconstruct the tensor, and feed it into the network. But it all depends of how you define your algorithm, your data and your input layer.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do. Input is meant to be 200 x 200 x 200 x 3.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, you're absolutely right about taking the name not the content. That `eval` inside the `save` call shouldn't be there. I also agree with `eval` being something to avoid, but how would you dynamically create variable names? Not sure about what you mentioned regarding `-struct`, it extracts the contents of a struct as independent variables, but I don't think that's what BNQ wanted to do.

Comment: You can do `s. (['tensor_' num2str(i)]) = ...` and then `save(...,'-struct',s)`. This will do the same thing as your code but without the `eval`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo could you expand on that? I can't manage to implement it.

Comment: @BNQ: where is the difficulty? Do you get an error message, wrong data in the file, something else? The struct creation statement is `s. (['tensor_' num2str(i)]) =  tensor;`. The save statement is `save('tensor.mat', '-struct', s, '-append');`. Make sure `s` doesn’t exist within your function, or pick a variable name that is not used before. You can initialize it with `s=[]` to make sure it doesn’t have a different value.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it says 

 `Error using save
The argument to -STRUCT must be the name of a scalar structure
variable.

Error in cube3 (line 164)
    save('tensor.mat', '-struct', str, '-append');`

Comment: @BNQ: That is what you should get from the code as I typed it. Take special note of "*Make sure `s` doesn’t exist within your function, or pick a variable name that is not used before.*" Since you use `str`, ensure it doesn't have other data in it by doing `str=[]; str.(...)=...`.